# CSS Property Backdrop filter not Working in Angular

Tags: angular

I have been trying to use backdrop-filter : blur(15px) in my angular component but it is not working

```
backdrop-filter : blur(15px);
```

Comment: Can you share more detail about the issue, on which component did you apply the styles? 
Are the styles in that components CSS? The problem MIGHT be due to Angular's View Encapsulation. Hence need more detail.

Comment: I was trying to style a div in my app.component.html with backdrop-filter : blur(15px) for glass morphism effect but it is not working

Comment: The component that you are applying backdrop-filter: blur should have a transparent background so that you can see the blur effect. But I can't say much with the detail provided. 
Give this a read maybe it'll help 
https://medium.com/featurepreneur/glassmorphism-effect-in-css3-988d7e8e92da

Comment: Take note: backdrop-filter is not by default compatible with Firefox. If you're using Firefox, read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter and click on FF in the Browser compatibility list to see what you need to do.